# Ubuntu 18 install - grub error : invalid buffer alignment

Tags: grub2

First question here, please let me know if i'm inaccurate.

I'm trying to install ubuntu 18 in dual boot with windows 10. I made my usb with rufus in gpt mode an i can boot on it but when i click on install ubuntu or try ubuntu without installing i obtain a black screen with the following output :

```
error : invalid buffer alignment -1070023623
error : you need to load the kernel first

Press any key to continue...
```

So i go into grub command-line and whichever command i use i obtain the following output :

```
error : invalide buffer alignment -1070023599
```

except with the command set which allows me to see a long lists of options, here are 4 of them as example:

```
?=29
cmdpath=(hd0,gpt1)/EFI/BOOT
prefix=(hd0,gpt1)/boot/grub
root=hd0,gpt1
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this so i can finish my install ?

Thanks guys !

Comment: Please verify the downloaded ISO used to make your installer matches its source: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Comment: Yes I have checked with sha256 and it was good

Comment: What is your hardware? What is "Ubuntu 18"?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to install Debian 10. It turned out that the supplier had formatted the disk as NTFS. I booted from a live CD, ran GParted to remove teh NTFS partition, and create the ext4 and lvm partitions that I wanted. The install then proceeded OK.

Answer (score 0):

Had similiar problem while trying to boot Ubuntu installed on external SSD. In order to repair this I had to boot from live USB (pendrive with Ubuntu image), download *boot-repair*, launch it, go into advanced options and in "GRUB options" select "Purge GRUB before reinstalling it" and then apply.

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar issue after installing onto a USB NVMe external drive - installation found the drive, installed perfectly and then on initial boot it comes up with this same message.

This, to me, points to a grub issue as my distro is CentOS 8 and the post is more a fyi and bread crumbs for other people searching the net for answers.

** if I select 'system setup' at the bottom of the grub menu and then select the same UEFI partition it boots without issue. Maybe hardware related? HP x360 Spectre (intel:1065g7 version)

Comment: This answer looks OK. I wonder why it was downvoted. Maybe it's because you suggested it's a grub issue, but it could also be a partitioning issue. The bright side is that if it is a partitioning issue then fixing it will make your CentOS boot normally. OTOH it might make it unable to boot at all. At least it boots now.